# Populate text box with value from MySql in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to display the values of a field in the MySql database, but everything I've tried ends up not populating the text box. Below is code I wrote off of some examples I found. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
    Dim sqlStripCmd As New MySqlCommand("ore_price_population", Mysqlconn)

    sqlStripCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim sdrstripcmd As MySqlDataReader = sqlStripCmd.ExecuteReader()


    Dim getDetailsDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim getDetailsDS As New DataSet
    getDetailsDA.SelectCommand = sqlStripCmd
    getDetailsDA.Fill(getDetailsDS, "getDetails")
    Veldspar_Isk.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables("Ore_Ice_Prices").Rows(0).Item("Veldspar").ToString()
```

SQL Query

```
    DELIMITER $$

    USE `YHI`$$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ore_price_population`$$

    CREATE DEFINER=`YHI`@`%` PROCEDURE `ore_price_population`()
    BEGIN

    SELECT `Veldspar`
    FROM
    `YHI`.`Ore_Ice_Prices`;
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: No, the program just doesn't populate the data into the field.

Comment: I'm not an expert on MySQL, but on the sqlCommand, I don't see any SELECT statement that will select the data from the tables.  "ore_price_population", is it a column from a table?  Please provide the complete code.

Comment: You are referencing a table named `Ore_Ice_Prices` but that table doesn't exist in your dataset

Comment: Auguste - I added the stored procedure.

Comment: Steve - would it be the "getDetails" name for the dataset?

Comment: No, it is the base name used for the tables. In your sp you have just one select so you have just one table and it is named "getDetails", DataSetName is "NewDataSet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass, as a second parameter, a string to the `MySqlDataAdapter.Fill` then the tables loaded by your stored procedure (one or many) are named according to this string. So you have a table named `getDetails` and if there are more table they are named `getDetails1` and so on.

But then you refer to a table named `Ore_Ice_Prices` that doesn't exist in your dataset.
This is one of the causes of your problem.

You need to use

```
Veldspar_Isk.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables("getDetails").Rows(0).Item("Veldspar").ToString
```

or

```
Veldspar_Isk.Text = getDetailsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Veldspar").ToString
```

There is another problem in your code. The line that builds an `MySqlDataReader` keeps the connection locked until you close the reader. This should trigger an exception in the following Fill call but I am not sure that this happens also in MySql as in Sql Server.

Comment: I do not have a try/catch. I tried both of your recommendations for the code, but both are returning back a blank field instead of populating the data. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Remove the creation of the MySqlDataReader. It is not needed and it keeps the connection locked until you close the reader. It should trigger an exception but I am not sure if it is the same in MySql

Comment: For your edit - That fixed the issue. thank you so much for your help! I'm going to reinstall VS since I am not getting any errors

Comment: Before this radical action look at the Debug menu subitem Exceptions and reset the values